# Datasource bean not autowired for security but JPA repository works

Tags: spring, spring-security, datasource, autowired

I'm trying to add spring security to a simple spring application (I want a login).

I have a JPA repository that works fine with my mysql database but when adding configuration for spring security it seems that the datasource bean is not found.

The error

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Websecurity config file where autowire happens

```
package com.example.configs;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");    }
}
```

Database configuration file

```
package com.example.configs;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Value("${db.driver}")
  private String DB_DRIVER;

  @Value("${db.password}")
  private String DB_PASSWORD;

  @Value("${db.url}")
  private String DB_URL;

  @Value("${db.username}")
  private String DB_USERNAME;

  @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
  private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

  @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
  private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

  @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
  private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

  @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
  private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

} // class DatabaseConfig
```

My application.properties file

```
# Thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false

# Database
 db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 db.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdb
 db.username: root
 db.password: 1234

# Hibernate
 hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
 hibernate.show_sql: true
 hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
 entitymanager.packagesToScan: com.example
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"but JPA repository works"*? The application fails to start up, how can you verify anything works?

Comment: @kryger I mean that de JPA repository was working fine with my database before adding spring-security, so I don't think it is a datasource configuration issue (I have seen people with similar issues with bad configuration for the database driver, for example).

Comment: Have you tried using `javax.sql.DataSource` rather than `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` inside `WebSecurityConfig`?

Comment: That was it, thank you! @kryger I am new to stackoverflow, can you tell me how I should close the topic properly?

Comment: I am having the same problem and I don't think it can work only by changing to javax.sql.DataSource. If you debug and put a break point in auth... section you will see that it is loaded first and can't find the Datasource. One solution is to move the datasource to external bean.